# "Wrap with " functionality disabled in flutter outline - Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have multiple flutter projects in Android studio, however for one specific project the Flutter outline "Wrap with " options are disabled. They are available for the other projects (Environment: macOS, Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2)

Any idea why these options are disabled and how to get them back?

[image: Android Studio Flutter Outline]

Comment: sdk is up to date in all of them -   sdk: ">=3.0.5 <4.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem.
Check these 2 things:

1. You gotta enable this Scope analysis to the current package option inside Dart Analysis to have it enabled. You find this at the bottom of the window.

[image]

2. Preferences > Intentions > search for dart > Check "Quick assists powered by Dart Analysis"

[image]

And you should be fine.